# Telegram бот не работает в беседе

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pythonanywhere, telepot

Развернул Telegram бота на pythonanywhere.

Тестируя бота в личных сообщениях с ним, всё работает, но вот уже в группе бот не работает.

/setprivacy - стоит Disable
/setjoingroups - стоит Enable

К боту как только не обращался @bot просто вводя команду, все равно не работает.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import telepot
import urllib3

proxy_url = "http://proxy.server:3128"
telepot.api._pools = {
    'default': urllib3.ProxyManager(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=3, maxsize=10, retries=False, timeout=30),
}
telepot.api._onetime_pool_spec = (urllib3.ProxyManager, dict(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=1, maxsize=1, retries=False, timeout=30))

secret = "SECRET"
bot = telepot.Bot('TOKEN')
bot.setWebhook("https://USERNAME.pythonanywhere.com/{}".format(secret), max_connections=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/{}'.format(secret), methods=["POST"])
def telegram_webhook():
    update = request.get_json()
    if "message" in update:
        chat_id = update["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        text = update["message"]["text"]

        if text == "!test":
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Privet, %s" % (update["message"]["from"]["first_name"]))

        if text == "!json":
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "%s" % update)
    return "OK"
```

Comment: У бота стоят админксие права в группе, все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе необходимо узнать айди твоей группы. затем сделать следующее и все будет работать. не забудь сделать админом бота и дать ему права:

```
GROUP_ID = 1234567 #ID группы
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id == GROUP_ID)
def tsak(message):
        pass
```